# Comparing player strengths and weaknesses

Tags: java

I'm developing a game which will have the same sort of system as pokemon does, i.e. every player will have a 'type'(fire,water,grass etc.). When players fight, I need to determine what factr to multiply attacks by, to create strengths and weaknesses. So far I'm using a switch in each 'type' class which takes another 'type' class as input and returns the multiplication factor. With only three of these 'type' classes, I'm writing a lot of ode and I can foresee it getting out of hand in the future when I want to add more.

So my question is, how can I implement a DRY solution for determining strengths and weaknesses of each type? I've attached a table of the pokemon types as a reference for what it is I am trying to do.[image]

Comment: Why a switch in each type? You could make a (static) method that tales two types, and returns the factor. But you'd still need to write every case I guess.

Comment: Have you considered using an external file to hold this data rather than hard coding it into the program? Anyway this game development stack exchange may be better placed to answer this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The way you just showed it: Put the elements in a matrix. Or map a pair of strings ("Ghost", "Dark") on a multiplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about enumerating the types, and building a 2D matrix that looks just like the one you posted. Whenever you need the "factor" for a battle, look the factor up using the attacker and defender as indices in the 2D array. Lookups would be fast and the code would be pretty clean.

Sample use cases would look something like this:

```
factor = factorTable[FIRE][WATER]; // would set factor to 0.5
factor = factorTable[WATER][FIRE]; // would set factor to 2.0
```

As Noctua suggested, it might be a good idea to have the actual data in a config file. That way you can easily change it without recompiling. If you go for that option, you'd need some kind of parsing function to create the matrix at the beginning of the program.

An even better step to take next would be to encapsulate the table behavior and type representation in classes. The underlying implementation could still be the same (or change, that's the point) but you wouldn't expose the table nor the enumerations directly.

```
factor = StrengthFactors(Player1.Type(), Player2.Type()); // or similar
```

Comment: This, but building it dynamically from a config file would be even better. Then you don't hard code the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a single array of strings to store the different types. Then you use a 2D Matrix to store multipliers. The idea is to use the id of this array of string to know where is the multiplier. You will have a O(n) complexity to find the multiplier you want.